# Spotify api put request “No token provided”

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, spotify

I try to add friend on spotify using spotify api but I get a 401 error : "No token provided" Here is the code :

```html
 console.log(token)
     this.http.put("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type="+userType+"&ids="+user2id,
        { headers: { 
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },}).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data)
        })
```

Output in console :

```html
BQBo6v6mah7hrnZb_yIlfb15YM04PX7LFlmzjarY6Qv3z_d8qPfYER2P7EzcFnWkg9iqP4hxkr4O-tJ_ssXv-6LC5q0znC0u6QPdrYI_8lI71emaqJ18zurFybbusbVBizSuWCbs_xzVMCcazSstO6VYqqKBDDwEhlI
```

Error :

```html
message: "Http failure response for https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=user&ids=21rppb3fgvjguagij4kl3ojda: 401 OK"

message: "No token provided"

status: 401
```

Edit: when I manually put a valid token just after the "bearer ", I get the same error

Comment: The curl request with your token seems to work perfectly in the terminal.  `curl -X PUT "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=user&ids=21rppb3fgvjguagij4kl3ojda" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQBo6v6mah7hrnZb_yIlfb15YM04PX7LFlmzjarY6Qv3z_d8qPfYER2P7EzcFnWkg9iqP4hxkr4O-tJ_ssXv-6LC5q0znC0u6QPdrYI_8lI71emaqJ18zurFybbusbVBizSuWCbs_xzVMCcazSstO6VYqqKBDDwEhlI"`

Comment: Check your dev console network tab, is the token getting attached to your request.